# GetWindowRect returning same value for left & right

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm trying to capture browser screenshot and one of my Win32 api method is GetWindowRect. This is returning same left & right value. This is only happen when I'm running my application in a remote machine having Win7 as a OS.

Also my PrintWindow method failing in this machine. If anyone have faced this issue before please let me know.

Those above two methods works fine with Vista and XP as OS in remote machine.

Adding few of the methods of my application.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);

    private Image Capture(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        Rectangle windowSize = this.GetWindowPosition(hwnd);

        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(windowSize.Width, windowSize.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
        {
            IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();

            if (PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, 0) == false)
            {
                throw new Exception("PrintWindow call failed");
            }

            g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            g.Flush();
        }

        return bm;
    }



    private Rectangle GetWindowPosition(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, ref r);

        return new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width, r.Height);
    }
```

Comment: Got code to share?  If you restart the applications after you establish the remote desktop session, does it work?

Comment: Is this code running in the browser process or elsewhere? Where did you get the HWND from?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't checking your Win32 return codes. My guess is that `GetWindowRect` fails for some reason and so doesn't assign any values to the rect. Thus its values remain uninitialised.

Check the return value and if the call fails use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` to find out why.  You'll need to update your P/Invokes too:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);
...
if (!GetWindowRect(hwnd, ref r))
    int ErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have checked Win32 return code & Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() return 0. Here are few more update on the problem.
I'm trying to capture screenshot in both IE & Chrome. When running in IE its failing in Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(windowSize.Width, windowSize.Height) line for 0 width & height. But when running in Chrome its getting proper height & width but its failing in PrintWindow step. In both cases Win32 return error code is 0. Thanks